# Microsoft SQL Server - Get first n alphanumeric characters with variable length, meeting ABCD-1234 or ABCD-1234567 format

Tags: sql-server-2019, substring

My MS SQL 2019 server version is 15.0.2080.9 (X64)

I have a table like

| id | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2003 | ABCD-1234: some text |
| 2897 | ABCD-5678 |
| 2456 | ABCD-675456: some text |
| 3204 | ABCD-4512345 :some text |
| 4567 | ABCD-2345 |

My requirement is to create another column in SELECT query, for each row to get like

| id | message | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | ABCD-1234: some text | ABCD-1234 |
| 2897 | ABCD-5678 | ABCD-5678 |
| 2456 | ABCD-675456 some text | ABCD-675456 |
| 3204 | ABCD-4512345 :some text | ABCD-4512345 |
| 4567 | ABCD-2345 | ABCD-2345 |

Meaning I need from position 0 till ABCD-1234 format is satisfied discarding empty or any other text after that.
I tried LEFT, RIGHT and Substring but could not find a way to get the exact length to meet the regex criteria from position 0.

Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case a SUBSTRING(,message, 1, 9)might work, as it always seems to have a lenght of 9. But I suspect that won't work in the real data as length varies??

Comment: Hi Peter, You are right, fixed length is not good for my requirement, it is a varied length of keys.

Comment: Hi Peter, I edited my question to show varied length to be clear, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PATINDEX` to find the start of a `LIKE` pattern. You can then pass that to `SUBSTRING` to get the bit before that position.

Be careful as `PATINDEX` can return `0` which you need to null out with `NULLIF`

```sql
SELECT *,
  [key] =
    ISNULL(
      SUBSTRING(
        t.message,
        1,
        NULLIF(
          PATINDEX(
            '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-]%',
            t.message
          ),
          0
        ) - 1
      ),
      t.message
    )
FROM YourTable t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yC-NmTLb)